# how to disable a searchable activity?

Tags: android

I make an app and use a property called "android.app.default_searchable" like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".ui.MainTabActivity" />
```

so that when I click the search button on the keyboard, it will jump to the specific activity.
but now I want some activities not to respond the search action. so how to config them in the manifest.xml or in other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the activities where you do NOT want search.  Tapping on the search button will do nothing.

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    return true;
}
```